# How do I model this pointed lancet window?

Tags: modeling

I have managed to do most of the window, but I am really struggling with the arch, I have tried the spin tool, but it can't quite manage the pointiness of the three arches.

[image: lancet windows]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> (or header menu > *Edge*) > *Bridge Edge Loops*, then you'll need to tweak the values in the *Operator* box (especially *Number of Cuts* and *Smoothness*) and probably edit a bit so that it matches your precise shape:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using *Proportional editing > Root* should get you pretty close.
Use more vertices on the sides for smoother result ;)

[image]